# How to make bPopup iframe the full width of the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bpopup

I am using the jQuery plugin bPopup, I am unable to post links, but it is easily found with  a quick search for bPopup

I have my css for the div as

```
min-width:800px;
```

and the popup itself is showing up with that size, but the iframe portion is only showing up as about 200 x 200 square, any ideas on how I can make the iframe the full width of the div is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you must change the size of the iframe too. iframe{min-width:800px}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css

```
iframe{min-width:800px}
```

Comment: OP already said he/she was using `min-width: 800px`... Edit: he said he had it on the `div`. I need to read :)

Comment: I have my css for the div as

min-width:800px; he/she didn't say the iframe was defined like that

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS do this:

```
.b-iframe{width:100%;}
```